# Is alienation (Heideggerian) related to assimilation and accommodation?

Tags: heidegger, being-and-time

According to [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=69BDC31DE587AAABBC081B4760EA9497?doi=10.1.1.672.6962&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> Dasein experiences being-in-the-world and thrown-ness with the
>   disclosure of this state through moods such as angst and boredom, in
>   which Dasein experiences a sense of alienation and inauthenticity or
>   discomfort with Dasein's thrown-ness in the world, or
>   being-in-the-world.

This reminds me of Piaget's learning theory, which says the mechanisms of assimilation and accommodation are the two main methods of learning. I thought these can to some extent explain why Dasein experiences a feeling of alienation while trying to involve into the world or the 'they'. Both are toilsome, at the least.

Am I right or are there any connections between these three concepts?

Comment: An interesting parallel (which Heidegger would likely reject, because to him he is investigating fundamental structures of being, not positive psychology), shared by some commentators, e.g. [Fontaine in Heideggerian Critique of the Role of 'Relation' in John Dewey's Philosophy of Education](https://fsu.digital.flvc.org/islandora/object/fsu:182552/datastream/PDF/view):"*one distinct advantage that Heidegger’s 
fundamental ontology enjoys... is that it points towards Piaget’s developmental psychology, and particularly towards his observation of how our brains make sense of the world.*"

Comment: @Conifold Oh, you are right. In The Ontological Priority of the Question of Being, Heidegger mentioned that. Scentists are mainly responsible for the ontical part and philosophers for the ontological part. I will read the paper, thanks.